# How can I undo an update function SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I used update statement on a column and now I want to reverse it. Is there a way to undo the this?

This is the original data

```
Name    Score
John    15
John    15
```

I used this query:

```
UPDATE T1
SET [score] = [score]+'na'
WHERE (name = ‘john’)
```

which gave me this:

```
Name    Score
John    15na
John    15na
```

Can I undo this and remove the `na`? I want the score to be a float.

Comment: did You try `rollback` ?

Comment: not yet, can you provide an example?

Comment: I just supose that You know `SQL`. In every DBS You have something like `commit` which makes data changes persistent and rollback which makes UNDO of all changes since last commit (some statements makes autocommits).

Answer (score 5):

Undo by removing the added `na`:

```
UPDATE T1
SET [score] = LEFT([score],LEN([score])-2)
where  (name = 'john')
```

Comment: @justiceorjustus Good point, but AFAICT removing the `na` from the string should make it a float even if it contained in a VARCHAR field. I am not sure that the OP actually wants to make the column a FLOAT type. If he does, I'll add something to do just that.

Answer (score 2):

You can either do as TT. has mentioned and update to its original value manually or `ROLLBACK`. If `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` is set to on you can `ROLLBACK` by executing `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;`. However if `EXPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` are set to on then you need to specify a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` like so...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE T1
SET [score] = [score]+'na'
where  (name = ‘john’);

--if unhappy with results..
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

or set `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` on if it is not already if you wish to `ROLLBACK` without specifying `BEGIN TRANSACTION` every time.

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;

UPDATE T1
SET [score] = [score]+'na'
where  (name = ‘john’);

--if unhappy with results..
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```